# EBCDIC to ASCII using XQuery in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery

I am newbie to xquery and MarkLogic. I wanted to know if there is any generalised method to convert an EBCDIC format file to ASCII file or any way that would help ?

Answer (score 1):

Content loaded into MarkLogic is always transcoded to UTF-8. You can specify the encoding of the source on an option to the function you use read the source:

```
xdmp:document-load("/path/to/my.xml", 
   <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
      <encoding>ebcdic-cp-us</encoding>
   </options>
)
```

The specific supported encodings are from ICU, do you can look them up at the[ICU page here](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/convexp).

If you want to return this back out as ASCII, you need to specify that in the output options. This could be on a specific API (e.g. xdmp:save) or as general rendering options for a query or for all queries on an appserver.

Comment: I am still stuck. Here is what I am trying.
1. Placed a EBCDIC format document in the directory where MarkLogic is installed using 
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:document-load("\MLJAM\trial1.ebc", 
   <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
      <encoding>ebcdic-cp-us</encoding>
   </options>
)

2. Tried returning the document back in ASCII using xdmp:save
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
  let $file := doc("\MLJAM\trial1.ebc")
  return
  xdmp:save("\MLJAM\mystuff2.txt", $file,
    <options xmlns="xdmp:save">
      <output-encoding>ASCII</output-encoding>
      <encoding>ASCII</encoding>
    </options>

Comment: The code is running fine but I am getting a weird output and not any ASCII formatted output.